# pixelated iphone UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I've been having issues rendering images with the UIImageView class. The pixelation seems to occur mostly on the edges of the image I am trying to show.

I have tried changing the property 'Render with edge antialiasing' to no avail.

The image files contain images that are larger than what will appear on the screen.

It seems to be royally messing with the quality of the image and then displaying it. I tried to post images here, but StackOverflow is denying me that privilege. So here's a link to what's going on.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuyy7.png

The sun in this image is the problem I'm speaking of. Any ideas?

Comment: This type of issue can occur in UI elements when the frame properties you specify (specifically the origin) are not integers. Try casting the dimensions with `(int)` when specifying the image view frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On-the-fly image resizing is quick and of low quality.  For bundled images, it is worth the extra bundle space to include downsized versions.  For downloaded images, you can achieve better results by resizing with Core Graphics into a new `UIImage` before you set the image property.

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, // context size
                                       NO,      // opaque?
                                       0);      // image scale. 0 means "device screen scale"
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
[bigImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following method use for get specific **hight** and **width** with **image**

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, with specific size that you specified.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your image and what is the size of the imageView?  Don't rely on UIImageView to scale it down for you.  You probably need to resize it manually.  This would also be a bit more memory efficient.

Comment: I will give this a go! I was suspicious of this all along.. Should've gone with my gut.

Answer (score 0):

I use categories like these:
[>>>github link <<<](https://github.com/mbcharbonneau/UIImage-Categories)

to do image resizing.

This also gives you some other nice function for rounded corners etc.

Also keep in mind, that you need a transparent border at the edge of an image if you want to rotate it to avoid aliasing.